# Using class constructors to set class variable array length

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, arguments

I have built a functioning b-tree. I utilized arrays for my child pointers and keys. What I want now is to be able to have my constructor take an array size argument (an integer) and have that determine my array length (aka whether it is a 3-4 or a 2-3 tree etc). I’m not allowed to use vectors. Im just now sure where to start.

Comment: If you can't use vectors, then use a dynamically sized array, like: `Child **array; … array = new Child*[N]`

Comment: But don't forget to delete said dynamically sized array, when you are done with it (typically, in a destructor of the class), to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Start with implementing a non-standard vector(-like) container.

Comment: Pro tip: If you need a vector, but your class doesn't let you use it, then write your own.  You don't need to do the full implementation though.  You just need enough to have an RAII type so you encapsulate the memory management.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `vector`, the purpose of this exercise is most likely that you practice manual memory management using methods you've learned recently.

Comment: *I’m not allowed to use vectors.*  --  I really don't understand these types of requirements.  You're supposed to be implementing a b-tree, not maintain a dynamic array,  It's not as if the code will magically write itself because a vector is used.  Now if your manual memory management (or home-made vector) is bugged, there goes your entire b-tree down the drain.

Comment: I forgot about dynamically sized arrays. That might work. So for my keys.... Key *array?

Comment: @BDHys -- Now is a good time to quickly prototype your solution using `std::vector`, since a vector is already bug-free.  Once you see that your solution works, then change the `std::vector` to a home-made one.  This way, at the very least, you could be sure your solution can work, with the extra step of translating over from using vector to a home-made class.